# Not finding the way to avoid nested loop. I'm running out og CPU time so the error is: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: trigger

This is my trigger.

```java
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {

    public static void updateWorkOrders(List<Case> triggerCases) {

        // TODO: Complete the method to update workorders
        List<Case> updatedCases = 
            [SELECT Id, Vehicle__r.Id, Product__c, Type, Status, Subject, ClosedDate, Date_Due__c, Date_Reported__c, CreatedDate,
             (SELECT Id, Equipment__c, Quantity__c, Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c, Maintenance_Request__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :triggerCases Limit 300];
        
        /*Map<Id, Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> emis2 = new Map<Id, Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>(
            [SELECT Maintenance_Request__c, Equipment__c, Quantity__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
             WHERE Maintenance_Request__c IN :updatedCases]);*/
        
        List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> emis = 
          [SELECT Maintenance_Request__c, Equipment__c, Quantity__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
           WHERE Maintenance_Request__c IN :updatedCases];
        
        List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> newEmi = new List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();
        
        List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();
        for(Case updatedCase : updatedCases) {
            
            /*if(emis.containsKey(updatedCase.Id)) {
                newEmi.add(new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c(
                    Equipment__c=emis.get(updatedCase.Id).Equipment__c,
                    Quantity__c=emis.get(updatedCase.Id).Quantity__c,
                    Maintenance_Request__c=updatedCase.Id
                ));
            }*/
            
            for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emi2 : emis) {
                newEmi.add(new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c(
                    Equipment__c=emi2.Equipment__c,
                    Quantity__c=emi2.Quantity__c,
                    Maintenance_Request__c=updatedCase.Id
                ));
            }
            
            List<Decimal> cycles = new List<Decimal>();
            for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emi : updatedCase.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) {
                cycles.add(emi.Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c);
            }
            
            cycles.sort();       
            if(cycles.size() > 0) {
                if(updatedCase.Status == 'Closed' && (updatedCase.Type == 'Repair') || (updatedCase.Type == 'Routine Maintenance')) {
                    newCases.add(new Case(
                        Vehicle__c=updatedCase.Vehicle__r.Id,
                        Product__c=updatedCase.Product__c,
                        Type='Routine Maintenance',
                        Subject='Routine Maintenance',
                        Date_Reported__c=Date.valueOf((updatedCase.CreatedDate)),
                        Date_Due__c=Date.valueOf((updatedCase.CreatedDate)).addDays(Integer.valueOf(cycles[0]))
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(newCases.size() > 0) {
            Database.insert(newCases);
        }

        if(newEmi.size() > 0) {
            for(Case newCase: newCases) {
                for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emi3 : newEmi) {
                    emi3.Maintenance_Request__c=newCase.Id;
            }
        }
        Database.insert(newEmi);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to advise what needs to be done here without a decent description of what your code is trying to accomplish.

#### First thing to note

Be aware that a limits exception only tells you where you went over the limit. That's not necessarily going to be the same class that caused you to use most/all of a particular limit.

To fix this, you're going to need to get a debug log and pore over it to find which part of the execution chain is actually causing you to burn through most of the governor limit at issue. It *could* be this class (and you should definitely work on improving it, even if it isn't the core issue), but it could also be a different class.

#### On nested loops

Nested loops are not inherently evil. When you're working with multiple levels of data, they *will* occur in some form or other. That's just a fact of programming life.

The ones that we want to avoid usually look something like this

```java
for(Account acct :allAccounts){
    for(Opportunity opp :allOpps){
        if(opp.AccountId == acct.Id){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

More generally, it's the "loop over every item in List Y for every item in List X" that's problematic.

In your code, you are iterating over every `Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c` for every `Case` instead of sticking to iterating over the `Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c` records related to *the specific case that you're working on in the loop*.

Your code doesn't *exactly* fit the bad nested loop pattern, but it's close enough to be a concern.

It's not clear to me why you need the query that is populating your `List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> emis` variable (you're already querying for EMIs related to each case in your query to populate `List<Case> updatedCases`). Without additional context, I can only see it and the subsequent nested loop over it as "bad, and should be removed". Surely Equipment__c, Quantity__c, and Maintenance_Request__c can be set within the same loop that you're adding things to `cycles`, no?

Answer (score 0):

My question would be what have you done to resolve this issue?

I would start with adding debug logs in the above code and see where it exceeds the limit.

`system.debug('***getCpuTime()***'+Limits.getCpuTime());`